# Accessing methods from children class in PHP object

Tags: php, class, inheritance, methods

I have two classes A and B, where B extends A and adds some methods. I have a class C with a method that accepts A as parameter for generalization purposes. The issue is that once inside the method, I want to access the methods of class B on the object, but I'm not able to do so. Don't get error, but have null in the return, when I have dumped the object and know that it holds data. 
Sorry if it's seems ridiculous, but I'm trying to use a bahaviour that you would expect in normal inheritance. Maybe be I'm missing something and it is my fault, but have no idea of what is happening here.
Please, if you have any idea of how to do this, help me.

Some code:

```
public function createProject(AssociatedProjectInterface $project_data){
        if(!is_a($project_data, 'class\path\GithubProject')){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The argument needs to be of type: GithubProject.');
        }


        $repo = $this->client->api('repo')->create(
            $project_data->getTitle(),
            $project_data->getDescription(),
            null,
            !$project_data->getIsPrivate(),
            null,
            $project_data->getIssuesEnabled(),
            $project_data->getWikiEnabled());
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any code that shows how you're trying to access this method?

Comment: Please show us a minimal code example.

Comment: Could you post some example? Also, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php come to mind.

Comment: Hold on please, I've spoted other things that migh be causing the problems. Sorry, my bad. Anyway, @GolezTrol, if you make your comment an aswer I'll select it if it really works like that, since it answer the doubt that is the root of my concern. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I've done that, given an answer that describes how method calling vs inheritance works in PHP. I hope it's sufficient and helps you find your problem, because frankly, I cannot tell by the code snippet you posted what exactly would be the problem.

Comment: As I wrote in previous comment, I found other stuff that might be responsible for the problem, but as my doubt on inheritance behavior persisted I appreciate your answer and selected it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that PHP's type checking is very loose. It calls the method of the class that is passed. The type checking is only taking place at the moment that function is called. So in the example below, `testType` must be past an object of type `A` or a descendant of `A`. After that initial check, no type checking is done at all! So the function can call any method declared in A or B. If a method is declared in both, it is considered overridden and the version in B is used.

```
<?php

class A {
  function foo() {
    echo 'A:foo';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  function foo() {
    echo 'B:foo';
  }

  function bar() {
    echo 'B:bar';
  }
}

function testType(A $a)
{
  $a->foo(); // B:foo
  $a->bar(); // B:bar <- This will succeed even though there's no bar() in A.
}

$a = new B();
testType($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for is NOT expected in normal object-oriented inheritance, but apparently works in PHP. Normally, if a method expects an object of class A, you can pass an object of class B that extends A, but the method will treat the object as though it were of class A. This means that when you call methods inherent to B, you are calling methods that don't exist and an error should be thrown.

In php though, momma don't care. As proof run the following minimal test:

```
<?php

class A {
  public function foo() {
    echo "in foo\n";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function bar() {
    echo "in bar\n";
  }
}

class C {
  public function test(A $b) {
    $b->foo();//works, because foo exists in the A class definition
    $b->bar();//also works for B, but not A
  }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$c = new C();
$c->test($b);
$c->test($a);//Will throw an error because the method bar() is not found
```

Note that it is considered *extremely bad* programming practice to ask for A when the code will quite literally die if it requires B. You should really avoid this situation.

Comment: This is not true. In general OOP when you call a method that exists in A and is overridden in B, the overridden method should be called. If you try to call a method that only exists in B, PHP will just call it. It doesn't care what you passed as long as it contains the method. The type hinting is only to check for the base type when the function is called but is not used further in the code (unfortunately). And above all, if you call a method that doesn't exist, PHP throws an error instead of returning null.

Comment: Your first statement is correct but irrelevant; he's not overriding a method. Regarding the other two; it's possible his errors are being suppressed somehow (@?), since we don't have minimal code we don't know. But in general with OOP such a call shouldn't return, and yes should throw an error.

Comment: Then, do it work as @GolezTrol says in the second sentence or not?

Comment: It does; apparently PHP class checking is quite loose! The above sample program shows that what you describe does work. @GolezTroi is correct, and if he posts a response I'll definitely upvote.